# Why does AWS EMR PySpark get stuck when I try to aggregate dataframe

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I'm running a Spark application in AWS EMR. The code is like this:

```
with SparkSession.builder.appName(f"Spark App").getOrCreate() as spark:
    dataframe = spark.read.format('jdbc').options(
        ...
    ).load()
    print("Log A")
    max_date_result = dataframe.agg(max_(date_format('date', 'yyyy-MM-dd')).alias('max_date')).collect()[0]
    print("Log B")
```

This application always gets stuck for a long time before failing. According to the log printed, I can see `Log A` at the end of the log file, but no `Log B`. So I think the application was stuck by the aggregation. Is there any problem with the aggregation? Also, I've found some questions about this problem, they are stuck on calling `collect()` because they are not using `SparkSession`, but I've already been using `SparkSession` now, it still doesn't work.

Here is some more log I found in EMR:

```
22/08/08 06:23:06 INFO JDBCRelation: Number of partitions: 11, WHERE clauses of these partitions: ...
22/08/08 06:23:07 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark-client://Executor) (172.31.9.57:58172) with ID 2,  ResourceProfileId 0
22/08/08 06:23:07 INFO ExecutorMonitor: New executor 2 has registered (new total is 1)
22/08/08 06:23:08 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager ip-***.us-west-1.compute.internal:37741 with 4.8 GiB RAM, BlockManagerId(2, ip-***.us-west-1.compute.internal, 37741, None)
22/08/08 06:23:10 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 274.762854 ms
22/08/08 06:23:10 INFO DAGScheduler: Registering RDD 3 (collect at spark_rds_parquet.py:136) as input to shuffle 0
22/08/08 06:23:10 INFO DAGScheduler: Got map stage job 0 (collect at spark_rds_parquet.py:136) with 11 output partitions
22/08/08 06:23:10 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ShuffleMapStage 0 (collect at spark_rds_parquet.py:136)
22/08/08 06:23:10 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
22/08/08 06:23:10 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
22/08/08 06:23:10 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ShuffleMapStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[3] at collect at spark_rds_parquet.py:136), which has no missing parents
22/08/08 06:23:10 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 3 executor(s) for resource profile id: 0.
22/08/08 06:23:10 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 47 executor container(s) to have a new desired total 3 executors.
22/08/08 06:23:10 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 23.8 KiB, free 1008.9 MiB)
22/08/08 06:23:10 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 11.6 KiB, free 1008.9 MiB)
22/08/08 06:23:10 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on ip-***.us-west-1.compute.internal:34379 (size: 11.6 KiB, free: 1008.9 MiB)
22/08/08 06:23:10 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1467
22/08/08 06:23:10 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 11 missing tasks from ShuffleMapStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[3] at collect at spark_rds_parquet.py:136) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
22/08/08 06:23:10 INFO YarnClusterScheduler: Adding task set 0.0 with 11 tasks resource profile 0
22/08/08 06:23:10 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (ip-***.us-west-1.compute.internal, executor 2, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4338 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
22/08/08 06:23:10 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) (ip-***.us-west-1.compute.internal, executor 2, partition 1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4342 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
22/08/08 06:23:10 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2) (ip-***.us-west-1.compute.internal, executor 2, partition 2, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4343 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
22/08/08 06:23:10 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) (ip-***.us-west-1.compute.internal, executor 2, partition 3, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4343 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
22/08/08 06:23:10 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark-client://Executor) (172.31.10.76:57610) with ID 1,  ResourceProfileId 0
22/08/08 06:23:10 INFO ExecutorMonitor: New executor 1 has registered (new total is 3)
22/08/08 06:23:10 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on ip-***.us-west-1.compute.internal:37741 (size: 11.6 KiB, free: 4.8 GiB)
22/08/08 06:23:10 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager ip-***.us-west-1.compute.internal:46531 with 9.7 GiB RAM, BlockManagerId(1, ip-***.us-west-1.compute.internal, 46531, None)
22/08/08 06:23:10 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 4.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 4) (ip-***.us-west-1.compute.internal, executor 1, partition 4, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4343 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
22/08/08 06:23:10 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 5.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 5) (ip-***.us-west-1.compute.internal, executor 1, partition 5, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4343 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
22/08/08 06:23:10 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 6.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 6) (ip-***.us-west-1.compute.internal, executor 1, partition 6, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4343 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
22/08/08 06:23:10 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 7.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 7) (ip-***.us-west-1.compute.internal, executor 1, partition 7, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4343 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
22/08/08 06:23:10 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 8.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 8) (ip-***.us-west-1.compute.internal, executor 1, partition 8, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4343 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
22/08/08 06:23:10 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 9.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 9) (ip-***.us-west-1.compute.internal, executor 1, partition 9, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4343 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
22/08/08 06:23:10 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 10.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 10) (ip-***.us-west-1.compute.internal, executor 1, partition 10, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4309 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
22/08/08 06:23:10 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on ip-***.us-west-1.compute.internal:46531 (size: 11.6 KiB, free: 9.7 GiB)
22/08/08 06:27:46 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) in 275934 ms on ip-***.us-west-1.compute.internal (executor 2) (1/11)
22/08/08 06:27:46 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) in 275949 ms on ip-***.us-west-1.compute.internal (executor 2) (2/11)
22/08/08 06:27:46 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2) in 276058 ms on ip-***.us-west-1.compute.internal (executor 2) (3/11)
22/08/08 06:27:46 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) in 276095 ms on ip-***.us-west-1.compute.internal (executor 2) (4/11)
22/08/08 06:27:46 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 2 executor(s) for resource profile id: 0.
22/08/08 06:27:47 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 9.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 9) in 276952 ms on ip-***.us-west-1.compute.internal (executor 1) (5/11)
22/08/08 06:27:47 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 5.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 5) in 277031 ms on ip-***.us-west-1.compute.internal (executor 1) (6/11)
22/08/08 06:27:47 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 7.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 7) in 277186 ms on ip-***.us-west-1.compute.internal (executor 1) (7/11)
22/08/08 06:27:47 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 4.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 4) in 277264 ms on ip-***.us-west-1.compute.internal (executor 1) (8/11)
22/08/08 06:27:47 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 1 executor(s) for resource profile id: 0.
22/08/08 06:27:48 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 8.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 8) in 277338 ms on ip-***.us-west-1.compute.internal (executor 1) (9/11)
22/08/08 06:27:48 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 6.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 6) in 277403 ms on ip-***.us-west-1.compute.internal (executor 1) (10/11)
22/08/08 06:28:46 INFO YarnClusterSchedulerBackend: Requesting to kill executor(s) 2
22/08/08 06:28:46 INFO YarnClusterSchedulerBackend: Actual list of executor(s) to be killed is 2
22/08/08 06:28:46 INFO ApplicationMaster$AMEndpoint: Driver requested to kill executor(s) 2.
22/08/08 06:28:46 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: Executors 2 removed due to idle timeout.
22/08/08 06:28:48 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Disabling executor 2.
22/08/08 06:28:48 INFO DAGScheduler: Executor lost: 2 (epoch 0)
22/08/08 06:28:48 INFO YarnClusterScheduler: Executor 2 on ip-***.us-west-1.compute.internal killed by driver.
22/08/08 06:28:48 INFO ExecutorMonitor: Executor 2 is removed. Remove reason statistics: (gracefully decommissioned: 0, decommision unfinished: 0, driver killed: 1, unexpectedly exited: 0).
22/08/08 06:28:48 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 2 from BlockManagerMaster.
22/08/08 06:28:48 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Removing block manager BlockManagerId(2, ip-***.us-west-1.compute.internal, 37741, None)
22/08/08 06:28:48 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removed 2 successfully in removeExecutor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out that problem was because Spark's predicate pushdown, Spark pushdown the filter to database and cause deadlock in database.

Comment: How do you know that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's not related to the creation of `SparkSession`, it's because your executor is being killed because of memory issue when it processes the specific task (partition 11). As some of your tasks are successful, I think you can try:

1. Please check if there is data skewness in particular partition, which make your executor fail on that task.
2. Increase the number of partition of your data.

Comment: I'm running the application on a cluster of three machines with 8 cores CPU and 32GB of memory, and the data I query from JDBC has only 10 million rows (less than 20GB), why could Spark use so much memory?

Comment: Hi @Neptune, first of all, 32GB memory doesn't mean that all 32GB memory are used in data storage. In fact, spark will split those memory to different parts. I think you can take a look in this post about the spark memory management and how to change the configuration, which give you a better understanding how spark use the memory: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Spark-Memory-Management/ta-p/317794. In your case, I think it's because of the data skewness in some partition and it overloads your memory.

Comment: skewness does necessarily mean a node fails.